# Why firefox can't open to parse my php in vim?

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, vim

A simple php file was edited in /var/www/html/tmp/test.php.

```
<html>
<p>haha</p>
<?php
echo "test";
?>
</html>
```

To open it in firefox 127.0.0.1/tmp/test.php  with firefox.

[image]
F12 was mapped to execute firefox to parse php file  in  the /etc/vim/vimrc.

```
nmap <F12>f :!firefox 'http://127.0.0.1/tmp/%'<CR>
```

Now to vim /var/www/html/tmp/test.php and press F12.
An ncredible  reaction  happened.
1.firefox was not called at all.
2.chrome was open to react,wrong result.

[image]

Comment: What is your defaumt browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see at least a couple of things wrong.

One, the mapping you wrote is **<F12>f** which would be F12 and then the letter F.

Two, **%** expands the relative path to the file, in this case `/var/www/html/tmp/test.php` as you're executing vim from the home directory. The expansion you're looking for is actually `%:t`

`:help expand`